# jQuery.addClass() behaviour, all at once

Tags: jquery, performance

I have this simple jQuery call to highlight a bunch of elements (couple thousand):

```
jQuery(elem).addClass('highlighted');
```

What the browser does is it quickly adds the class, but does not repaint the element. Is there a way to render each "highlighted" element as soon as i add the class. Right now the user sees a stutter until my loop of adding the class have finished.

---

### EDIT:

More code:

```
var elem = findNext(); // walks the dom and finds next search match. ~10ms each call
while(elem){
   highlight(elem);
   elem = findNext(); 
}

function highlight(elem){   
   jQuery(elem).addClass('highlight');
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, including the "elem" selector and a few lines of surrounding code for context.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is really in the findNext() method.  10 ms is a large amount of time, especially if you're iterating over thousands of records.

Answer (score 3):

This is because DOM changes are not rendered as long as a JavaScript function is running. User interface code is single-threaded and a browser locks while executing it. Normally this is not problem because JS is quite fast and functions do not run very long. But *if* they do, you see sluggish behavior as a result.

Your function needs to stop in the middle of its work to give the browser a chance to become responsive again. You can solve this by using `setTimeout()` and remembering where you left off.

This should give you an idea:

```
// prepares a closure function to handle affected elements in chunks of n
function updatePartial(elems, chunksize) {
  var current = 0;
  return function() {
    // changes n elements in a loop
    for (var i=0; i<chunksize; i++) {
      jQuery(elems[current+i]).addClass('highlighted');
    }
    current += chunksize;
    // calls itself again after a short break
    if (current < elems.length) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
  }
}

// aquire and execute the closure function
updatePartial(jQuery("selector").get(), 100)();
```

(Tested at http://jsfiddle.net/fPdAg/)

Closures are an elegant way of avoiding global variables you would need in other implementations.

---

EDIT: A generalized version of the above would be this:

```
// prepares a closure function to handle affected elements in chunks of n
function updatePartial(elems, chunksize, payload) {
  var current = 0;
  return function() {
    // changes n elements in a loop
    for (var i=0; i<chunksize; i++) {
      // apply the payload function to current element
      payload.apply(elems[current+i]);
    }
    current += chunksize;
    // calls itself again after a short break
    if (current < elems.length) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
  }
}

// aquire and execute the closure function, supply custom payload function
updatePartial(jQuery("selector").get(), 100, function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass('highlighted');
})();
```

Comment: jsFiddle is awesome!! Thanks for that unrelated tip.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because the browser behavior, not the JQuery problem.
When call

```
jQuery(elem).addClass('highlighted');
```

While **Javascript** runnig, the browser stop working until JS finish its execution. So browser **will not repain** anything until JQuery addClass to every element.
Let try this trick

```
<script>
x = jQuery(elem).size();
y = number_item_each_time;
z = time_by_micro;
start = 0;
t = setInterval(function(){
      $(elem).slice(start, start + y).addClass('highlighted');
      start = start + y;
      if(start > x)
          clearInterval(t);
  }, z);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the browser is quickly adding the class?  It sounds like it takes a noticeable amount of time to complete the operation, which is what I'd expect.

You could try batching the addClass() calls into a series of setTimeout callbacks (e.g. 10 calls that each do 100 elements) to show the result more quickly.

**Update**

I just noticed that you said "until my loop of adding the class have finished".  Are you making a single call to addClass, or calling it individually for each element inside a for loop?

You should definitely be making a single call a la `jQuery('.all-your-elements').addClass('highlighted')`.  It will be more readable and much faster.

Comment: i am making an individual call per element. The elements come from a search function that is somewhat complex for straight jQuery(criteria). I can send a whole array into highlighting, but like you saw the browser shows results after i'm done searching elemetns, adding highlight class to them. About 1-2 seconds too late.

Comment: You might still get a benefit from adding the elements to a jQuery array and calling addClass once at the end.  But as I mentioned in my comment in your original question, I think your problem is in your search algorithm, not the loop that adds the class.

Answer (score 0):

Check out solution using only jQuery 1.4.2 (without setTimeout)
It uses queue on $(document) to postpone function execution
and execute them in order.

http://jsfiddle.net/xXGz3/

```
  $(function() {
      $('.highlight').each(function() {
          var e = $(this);
          $(document).delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
              e.addClass('a');
              next();
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: I don't want to delay my other js functions purposely. The opposite, i want the browser to re-render the highlight as soon as I set it.

Comment: You can move this to html5 worker (http://blog.mozbox.org/post/2009/04/10/Web-Workers-in-action), but not all browsers supports them.
Current javascript implementations single-threaded, they do one thing at a time. No concurrency allowed.